# labelPlacement of MUI FormControlLabel not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the `FormControlLabel` component from MUI and the label is always getting placed at the end, even if I set the `labelPlacement` prop to "start", "top" or "bottom".

This is my code:

```
              <FormControlLabel
                label="Connected account"
                labelPlacement="start"
                control={
                  <MDBox display="inline">
                    <MDTypography variant="caption" mr={2}>
                      Account Name
                    </MDTypography>
                    <MDButton
                      color="error"
                      size="small"
                      sx={{ m: "0.25rem" }}
                      onClick={() => disconnectAccount(idAccount)}
                    >
                      <MDTypography
                        fontSize="0.6rem"
                        color="white"
                        fontWeight="bold"
                        textTransform="uppercase"
                      >
                        Remove Account
                      </MDTypography>
                    </MDButton>
                  </MDBox>
                }
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: "#f7fafc",
                  mb: "1rem",
                  borderRadius: "0.5rem",
                  pl: "1rem"
                }}
              />
```

This is what the UI looks like with `labelPlacement` set to "end" and "start", respectively, meaning a left margin is added when set to "start":

[image]
[image]
Am I missing something here?

Comment: `labelPlacement` does not appear anywhere in the code you've posed.

Comment: @RockySims thanks for pointing that out. I've included it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect it's because the parent element is narrow enough that 'start' or 'end' both appear the same (though I can't be sure). Does this example help? https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-lichterman-lyfx5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: That could be the reason. I'll take a look at it and get back to you if it works.

Comment: The example you provided is what I'd like mine to look like. I'm doing exactly what you did and the `FormControlLabel` takes up the full width, so I don't think there is a problem with the width. I've included screen grabs showing when `labelPlacement` is set to "end" and "start".